# SWIFT: How to display activity indicator when user clicks on Tab Bar

Tags: xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to add an activity indicator when a user clicks on my tab bar menu but it seems complicated actually.

I have 4 tab bar items and they parse a json from an URL. My problem is when the user clicks on tab bar item and the screen just freezes before show the next view. I would like to change to the view and then show an activity indicator while they make the url petition and parse the item.

I have one class that conform the UITabBarController method, but I'm reading some exemples in Objective-C that they talk about UITabBarDelegate.

How can I try to solve this? I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Your question is way too vague. Usually you'll want to load and parse the data asynchronously, and display it when it's done parsing. How you do that depends on the structure of your program, which you haven't really told us about.